# Why don't form tags work after a div

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form which has a div tag within it to help style the second part of my form into a second column. However my close form tag now doesn't work. Is there a reason why?

I have a localstorage.js which is working perfectly up until `<div id="form-group">`. Please, help! I'm so close to completing this page.

```
<div id="section">  
    <form id="franchiseForm" action ="javascript:void(0);" method="POST">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="fran_name">Franchise Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="franchise_name" id="fran_name" placeholder="e.g One Delivery Leeds" pattern="[a-zA-Z]"                         autofocus required tabindex="1">
            <br>
        </div>
        <div id="form-group">
            <p>Opening Hours</p>
            <div>
                <label for="Monds"> Monday </label>
                <input type="text" name="Mon" id="Mon" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="8">
                <span>-</span>
                <input type="text" name="Monday" id="Monday" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="9">
                <hr />
             </div>
             <div>
                 <div class="line-separator"> </div>

                 <div class="field">
                     <input type="submit"  value="Save">
                 </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: *"my close form tag now doesn't work"*. What does it mean?

Comment: my text editor tells me there is a mistake on the line of my close from tag. but if i move the tag above the div id, my text editor tells me its fine

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to close a `<div>` tag. Use this:

```
<div id="section">  
  <form id="franchiseForm" action ="javascript:void(0);" method="POST">
    <div class="field">
      <label for="fran_name">Franchise Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="franchise_name" id="fran_name" placeholder="e.g One Delivery Leeds" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" autofocus required tabindex="1">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="form-group">
      <p>Opening Hours</p>
      <div>
        <label for="Monds"> Monday </label>
        <input type="text" name="Mon" id="Mon" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="8">
        <span>-</span>
        <input type="text" name="Monday" id="Monday" class="open_hours" placeholder="--:--" required tabindex="9">
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="line-separator"> </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

You can check markup errors with an HTML validator. [This one](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) is good enough for most cases.

Comment: @AsadPalekar I count just one.

Comment: My bad. i was mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for that. I checked it says my div inside a form is invalid. All my divs are also closed, my editor highlights the divs which are not closed in red

Answer (score 0):

You have unclosed div tags try closing them. close the `<div id="form-group>` and the div before `<div class= "line-seprator">`

Comment: Thanks you, All my divs are also closed, my editor highlights the divs which are not closed in red